# How to format a binding to double like this ######.## using culture?

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I have a double value on my ViewModel and want to bind a TextBlock's Text, such that:

128228.094545 gets formatted to 128228[x]09, where [x] is the decimal separator according to the computer's culture settings.

I've tried:

```
Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{}{0:F2}'}"
```

Doesn't work: The value gets displayed 128228.09 regardless of the correct decimal separator symbol.

```
Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{}{0:N2}'}"
```

Renders digit grouping symbol ([d], y in en-US), which I don't want: 128[d]228[x]09

```
Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"
```

Obviously doesn't work.

What's the right formatting string?

Comment: Haven't worked with WPF yet, but wouldn't `StringFormat='{}{0:######.##}'` (or simply `StringFormat='{}{0:#.##}'`)  work?

Comment: Nope, because that renders a '.' always,, although the culture might have a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that when StringFormat is used in a data binding it does not honor the current culture.

In the past I've used a simple [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to format the value. This can be useful if your application allows a user to specify the format options for all numbers e.g. number of decimal places. Alternatively you can use the ConverterParameter to specify the format string and simply return:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, converterParameter, value)
```

If you don't need to surround the value with a prefix or suffix the following converter should allow you to convert to and from formatted values:

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (value != null && parameterString != null)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:"+ parameterString + "}", value);
        }
        else
        {           
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof (double))
        {
            return System.Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        else if (targetType == typeof(int))
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        // Any other supported types
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me thanks, do you mind posting the ConvertBack? To you handle every possible number TargetType seperately?

Comment: Based on the TargetType you should be able to use System.Convert i.e. `System.Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`. I'll try and update the answer later.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first definition is correct. Thing is that the formatting is always done based on the culture which is set. Don't know what exactly you are using but it depends how to set the culture for your app.

Here is a great blog post describing it for WPF because there are some issues defining the culture manually...

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting

Comment: I want the current culture to be applied, not a custom culture, but WPF obviously ignores it..